# Cargar funciones de un fichero javascript externo a otro

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-import

Por motivos de organización,  me gustaría que mi contenido estuviera un poco más "clasificado" y estoy creando ficheros .js que compartan contenido y funciones.

El problema viene cuando intento incorporar ese contenido a otros ficheros .js, estoy utilizando import/export pero no consigo que funcione:

fichero1.js

```
 export default function puntos() {mis datos y funciones}
```

ficheroPrincipal.js

```
import {puntos} from 'fichero1';
```

Me da errores de este tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Javascript en el navegador? ¿Cómo has añadido esos archivos a la página HTML?

Comment: En realidad solo añado el fichero principal, debería añadir ambos?